# Parse a string using keywords

Tags: bash, awk, sed, cut

I am using a bash command, `gps location`, that returns a date, time and location information.

```
[john@hostname :~/develp] $ gps location
Location: {"date": "16/07/20", "time": "19:01:22", "latitude": "34.321", "longitude": "133.453", "altitude": "30m"}
```

I want to write the longitude to a file, before I get there I need to correctly parse the string.

```
[john@hostname :~/develp] $ variable=`gps location | awk '/"longitude":/ {print $9}'`
[john@hostname :~/develp] $ echo $variable
"133.453",
[john@hostname :~/develp] $
```

Currently, `awk` isn't searching for longitude, it solely is taking the whole string and finding the 9th string. Ideally, I would like to use a regex/keyword approach and find longitude and then the next string after. I have tried using `grep | cut` also tried `sed`. No luck, best I can do is using `awk`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Strip off the `Location:` and you're left with JSON:

```
$ echo '{"date": "16/07/20", "time": "19:01:22", "latitude": "34.321", "longitude": "133.453", "altitude": "30m"}' |
    jq .longitude
"133.453"
```

See in the man page if `gps` has an option to not print the `Location:` keyword up front, if not stripping it is easy, e.g.:

```
$ echo 'Location: {"date": "16/07/20", "time": "19:01:22", "latitude": "34.321", "longitude": "133.453", "altitude": "30m"}' |
    cut -d':' -f2- | jq .longitude
"133.453"
```

or:

```
$ echo 'Location: {"date": "16/07/20", "time": "19:01:22", "latitude": "34.321", "longitude": "133.453", "altitude": "30m"}' |
    sed 's/Location://' | jq .longitude
"133.453"
```

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to leave comments, but to expand upon Ed Morton's answer: if you call `jq` with the `-r` option, it will automatically strip quotes when the output is just a string (as it is in your case):

```
$ echo 'Location: {"date": "16/07/20", "time": "19:01:22", "latitude": "34.321", "longitude": "133.453", "altitude": "30m"}' | cut -d':' -f2- | jq -r .longitude
133.453
```

Comment: Ah, good thanks David.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to try this without `jq` (e.g. because it is unavailable), *and* the output is always a one-liner as implied by your example, the following `sed` approach would also work:

```
sed -r 's/.*"longitude": "([^"]+)".*/\1/'
```

This will

- look for a string enclosed in double-quotes ( `"([^"]+)"`, i.e. starting `"` followed by a string containing "anything but `"`" until the closing `"`), where the enclosed content is defined as "capture group" `( ... )`, that occurs immediately after a string `"longitude":`
- and replace basically the entire line with the content of the capture group (`\1`) - in your case, the actual value of the longitude

Test:

```
~$ echo 'Location: {"date": "16/07/20", "time": "19:01:22", "latitude": "34.321", "longitude": "133.453", "altitude": "30m"}' | sed -r 's/.*"longitude": "([^"]+)".*/\1/'
133.453
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the substring using bash builtins, specifically by using only parameter substitutions:

```
v=$(gps location)
v1=${v#*\"longitude\":\ \"}
echo "${v1%%\"*}"
```

Wherein we remove everything upto `longitude": "` in the variable v starting from left. Then in the next step we remove everything upto the last " starting from right. What remains are the longitudinal coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

if you can't install jq, you can do it in pure bash using a loop over cut.

```
i=1
words=$(gps location)
word=$(echo $words | cut -d',' -f$i)
while ( [ -n "$word" ] )
  do
  echo $word | grep longitude | cut -d' ' -f2
  (( i+=1 ))
  word=$(echo $words | cut -d',' -f$i)
done
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. May I recommend that you always quote shell variables and command substitutions unless you know exactly that you don't want it (e.g. because you need word splitting by the shell)?

Comment: That'll be **extremely** slow and buggy. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) and copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net to see some of the issues.

Comment: Thanks @AdminBee. I didn't know that. I was looking for something similar on a high performance computer cluster running scientific linux. Even the most basic awk things (like print) kept failing, so I had to go and either pipe everything through a c++ program or use pure bash. Might be slow, but can't see why buggy.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

```
grep -o longitude.:.* < in | grep -o '[0-9.]*' | head -1

grep -o longitude.:.* < in | cut -f3 -d'"'
```

People often forget the humble `tr`:

```
grep -o longitude.:.* < in | tr -dc 0-9., | cut -f1 -d,
```

or even better:

```
tr -dc ' La-z0-9.' < in | grep -o longitude.[0-9.]* | cut -f2 -d' '
```

That last one will make more sense if you realise that the first step produces

```
Location date 160720 time 190122 latitude 34.321 longitude 133.453 altitude 30m
```

which as you can see removes a lot of the distraction :-)

Answer (score 0):

Done with below awk command and it worked fine

cat filename

```
Location: {"date": "16/07/20", "time": "19:01:22", "latitude": "34.321", "longitude": "133.453", "altitude": "30m"}
```

command

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /latitude/){print $(i+1)}}}' filename
```

output

```
"34.321"
```

Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
a="""Location: {"date": "16/07/20", "time": "19:01:22", "latitude": "34.321", "longitude": "133.453", "altitude": "30m"}"""

b=a.split(":")
for i in range(0,len(b),1):
    if "longitude" in b[i]:
        print b[i+1].split(",")[0]
```

output

```
 "133.453"
```